# Write to socket after FIN exception handling

Tags: node.js

If client socket send FIN and server trying send data to this socket, server crashed. How to handle this error?

I have code like this:

```
client.write(data);
```

I must use process.on('uncaughtException') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch these errors by listening for the special `error` event on the same object:

```
client.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Uh oh, an error occurred: ' + err);
});

// ...

client.write(data);
```